# How to give text file as input in command line for console application ... C# Program

Tags: c#

I have written a program in console application .I am facing problem to upload text file in command line.. If I Place direct path
 "string s = File.ReadAllText("E:/Aspdot.txt");" like this in programming its ok working fine. But instead of that I would like to upload or mention path while runtime as commanline input.

Here I am placing my trails ... Can anybody suggest me how do that....

```
class Program
{
 static void Main()
 {
    // 1.
    // Array to store occurances.
    int[] c = new int[(int)char.MaxValue];

    // 2.
    // Read entire text file.
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your text file path");
    String a = Console.ReadLine();
    //string s = File.ReadAllText("E:/Aspdot.txt");
    string s = File.ReadAllText(a);

    // 3.
    // Iterate over each character.
    foreach (char t in s)
    {
        // Increment table.
        c[(int)t]++;
    }

    // 4.
    // Write all letters found.
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)char.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        if (c[i] > 0 &&
            char.IsLetter((char)i))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Letter: {0}  Occurances: {1}",
                (char)i,
                c[i]);

        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
 }

}
```

Comment: What is the question ? Your code example doesn't really explain what you want to upload, to where, or what you are having problems with.

Comment: If I specify direct path in program like this string s = File.ReadAllText("E:/Aspdot.txt"); Its working fine.. But instead of  that.. I would like to mention my Aspdot.txt file in runtime.... For that.. I am looking for solution.. Can anybody please suggest me ?

Answer (score 12):

### ①

Use a command-line parameter:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please specify a filename as a parameter.");
        return;
    }

    var fileContents = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);

    // ... do something with the file contents
}
```

Then you can call the program like this:

```
MyProgram MyFile.txt
```

### ②

Read the file from STDIN:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var fileContents = Console.In.ReadToEnd();

    // ... do something with the file contents
}
```

Then you can call the program like this:

```
MyProgram < MyFile.txt
```

or

```
type MyFile.txt | MyProgram
```

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the program and see how the actual string being input is coming out of the Console.ReadLine() statement. My guess is that the ReadLine is escaping certain characters like backslashes. It may also include the newline character, which is invalid in a path.